# Como fazer um subset em uma série do tipo zoo escolhendo certos anos ou meses?

Tags: r, series-temporais

Eu tenho a seguinte série:

```
library(zoo)

zoo_serie <- zoo(1:length(seq.Date(as.Date("1991-12-01"),as.Date("1998-12-31"),'day')),seq.Date(as.Date("1991-12-01"),as.Date("1998-12-31"),'day'))
```

Quero fazer um subset para os anos de 1991, 1995 e 1997, como faço isso de forma ágil?

Atualmente eu crio uma série de datas e depois faço o index na série, isso não se torna viável para séries enormes.

```
zoo_serie[index(zoo_serie) %in% vetor_de_datas]
```

Queria algo como assim:

```
zoo_serie[year(index(zoo_serie)) %in% c(1911,1995,1997)]
```

Mas não funciona. Da mesma forma queria para meses específicos, essa forma ainda não consegui.

Comment: A função `year` do pacote `lubridate` faz exatamente isso. O pacote tem mais funções para extrair meses, dias e outras informações de datas.

Comment: @jorge-mendes, coloque isso como uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicado por @jorge-mendes nos comentários, o pacote lubridate tem vária funções para trabalhar facilmente com datas e faz exatamente o que deseja. Vou usar um exemplo menor que o seu para facilitar a visualização:

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)

datas <- as.Date(c("1991-03-23", "1992-05-28", "1994-03-07", "1995-11-14", "1996-07-23"))
zserie <- zoo(seq(length(datas)), datas)

anos.sel <- c(1991, 1995, 1996)

zserie[year(index(zserie)) %in% anos.sel]
#> 1991-03-23 1995-11-14 1996-07-23
#>          1          4          5

zserie[month(index(zserie)) == 3]
#> 1991-03-23 1994-03-07
#>          1          3
```

Pode-se também usar expressões regulares:

```
zserie[grep(paste(anos.sel, collapse = "|"), index(zserie))]
#> 1991-03-23 1995-11-14 1996-07-23
#>          1          4          5

zserie[grep("-03-", index(zserie))]
#> 1991-03-23 1994-03-07
#>          1          3
```

Comment: +1 pelo extra das expressões regulares